# Fastest way to select from a table with milions of records

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with millions of records and I want to select all of them and put them into a dataTable.

Here is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["A"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM B", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

It takes a lot of time. What is the fastest way to select?

Comment: A lot of records will lead to a lot of time. Do you really need all records at once? Consider paging.

Comment: It can't get any simpler than what you currently have. As @Zohar said, consider paging or find what data you actually need instead of pulling all the data at once.

Comment: If you are using datatables, please read data in ajax way. It means select suppose 50 records in one go and add it in datatable.  Use pagination to fetch next 50 records on second page. Or make chained ajax calls to fetch data maintaining index which is the better way according to me

Comment: Would you please give me an example of using ajax?